# Remove buttons from redactor wysiwyg

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, redactor

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/KfVJK/

This is the code to add redactor:

```
$(document).ready(
            function()
            {
                $('#redactor_content').redactor();
            }
        );​
```

I want to limit the number of buttons on the toolbar. For example only have basic formatting like bold, italic, etc.

How can I remove buttons from the toolbar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `buttons` setting:

```
var buttons = ['formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic'];

$('#redactor').redactor({buttons: buttons});
```

This is extract from [documentation](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/):

> By default, this setting contains the following array of toolbar's
>   buttons:
>
> ```
> ['html', '|', 'formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', '|', 
> 'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', '|',
> 'image', 'video', 'file', 'table', 'link', '|',
> 'fontcolor', 'backcolor', '|', 'alignment', '|', 'horizontalrule']
>
> // additional buttons
> // 'underline', 'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'justify'
> // If you wish to set your own array, set it in this option:
>
> $('#redactor').redactor({
>     buttons: ['html', '|', 'formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic'] 
> });
> ```

Answer (score 7):

After go through their [docs](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/toolbar/), I would suggest you to setting your button as following:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    buttons: ['formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic'] 
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/KfVJK/3/